# Way to transfer operational data to anyalystical (reporting) data

Tags: sql-server, database, batch-processing

I have two database table A and table B, both are operational tables. The table A and table B contains highly normalized data, only foreign keys and numerical data.

I wants to transfer table A and table B data to highly denormalized multiple tables (reporting tables) at every 10 minutes.

There are multiple operations need to perform on table A and table B to convert it to reporting data like joins on foreign keys and aggregation.

The both tables, operational and reporting tables are in same database schema.

Should I use trigger (I heard some bad things about trigger!), scheduled job, web service or something else to implement this.

Comment: Conventional wisdom is a scheduled job, but I've never worked with `demoralized` tables before.

Comment: I guess that's denormalized

Comment: You could also investigate using an indexed view,,, similar to materialized views in Oracle.

Comment: Sorry Tab...its denormalized table.